# JavaScript 360 spinning with OBJ file

Tags: javascript, jquery, 360-degrees

I know this is a bad place to ask a generic question but i am working on a project where the designer would like a 360 degree rotating image of a vehicle and I am sure they will be giving me a 3D model (probably .obj). I need it to spin front, side, to back and not top to bottom or in the Z-space.

I have looked at a lot of 360 spinners and they like between 72-360 images to create the effect.

Does anyone know if a 360 degree spin can be done with JS using a OBJ and, bonus points, can hot spots be added to it?

Thank you and let know if anyone has had this issue before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The most well-known framework is Three.js, which just so happens to [come with an .obj loading example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obj#webgl_loader_obj2) with a model you can spin around.

Adding hot spots would involve adding hot spots like in [some of the interactivity demos](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes).